# ClassCastException user object hierarchy in Grails using SpringSecurityCore Plugin

Tags: grails, spring-security, classcastexception

I´ve got some weird behaviour using Grails 2.2.4, SpringSecurityCore 2.0 RC in Production on a Tomcat 7 with Groovy Compiler 2.0.8, Java 1.7.0.

We build a plugin which realize basic behaviors. We included the SpringSecurityCore plugin in it with a person class named User. There are some domain classes in the basic plugin which got User fields.

Then we build an application which include our basic plugin. The application got a special application person class called RUser which extend from User. RUser is set to SpringSecurityCore as person class.

**Problem:**

The application runs about 1 to 3 days without errors, but then ClassCastExceptions are thrown trying to set a RUser object on a User field of a plugin domain class.

User classes:

```
Plugin User class:

class User implements Serializable {
  transient springSecurityService
  String username
  String password
  ...
}

Application User class:

class RUser extends User implements Serializable{
  Cart cart 
  boolean businessUser = false
  boolean taxIncluded = false
  ...
}

Application Config.groovy:
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'RUser'
```

Participated classes of our basic plugin:

```
class UserRole implements Serializable {
  User user
  Role role

  static UserRole create(User user, Role role, boolean flush = false) {
    new UserRole(user: user, role: role).save(flush: flush, insert: true)
  }
 ...
}

class UserHistory implements Serializable{
  User user
  List historyEntries
  static hasMany = [historyEntries:HistoryEntry]
  ...
}
```

The errors occur in this example situations:

In a Filter:

```
54: UserHistory.withTransaction{
      def currentUser =springSecurityService.currentUser
      def history = UserHistory.findByUser(currentUser)
      if(!history){
96:     history = new UserHistory(user:user).save(flush:true)
      }
    }

2014-05-23 13:52:17,279 ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver| IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /index
java.lang.ClassCastException@7ff92284. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:687)
at de.neomatt.history.HistoryFilters$_closure1_closure2_closure4.doCall(HistoryFilters.groovy:54)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at de.neomatt.history.HistoryFilters$_closure1_closure2_closure4_closure5.doCall(HistoryFilters.groovy:96)
... 10 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'springSecurityService' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@7ff92284
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@7ff92284
... 13 more
2014-05-23 13:52:17,288 ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver| IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /reservation_demo/ToolsOne
Method name must not be null. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Method name must not be null
at grails.plugin.cache.web.ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.retrieveAction(ProxyAwareMixedGrailsControllerHelper.java:41)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

In a Controller:

```
    RegistrationCode.withTransaction {
     def user = lookupUserClass().findByUsername(registrationCode.username)
     def role = Role.findByAuthority(roleName)
281: UserRole.create user, role
    }

2014-05-26 13:02:24,780 ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver| IllegalArgumentException occurred when processing request: [GET] /app/register/verifyRegistration
java.lang.ClassCastException@a7c83d. Stacktrace follows:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@a7c83d
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at de.neomatt.security.UserRole.create(UserRole.groovy:32)
at de.neomatt.security.RegisterController$_closure4_closure14.doCall(RegisterController.groovy:281)
at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormStaticApi.withTransaction(GormStaticApi.groovy:687)
at de.neomatt.security.RegisterController$_closure4.doCall(RegisterController.groovy:271)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter.doFilter(PageFragmentCachingFilter.java:195)
at grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter.doFilter(AbstractFilter.java:63)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:53)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter.java:49)
at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.java:82)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

The ClassCastExceptions occurs everywhere, where an object with type RUser is setted on a User field. The RUser object is retrieved from springSecurityService.currentUser or with the lookupUserClass().findBy(...) method.

```
protected Class<?> lookupUserClass() {
  grailsApplication.getDomainClass(lookupUserClassName()).clazz
}
```

As mentioned before, the application runs without errors for a undefined period of time in a production environment (no reloading, no config changes). A new deployment of the same war solves the problem for the next few hours/days.

Any suggestions?

@neomatt

Comment: This is weird. Needs to simulate your code, but for now you can use **User** domain in place of **RUser** class. Since you can overwrite the domain classes from plugins within the same package. What I mean to say is, define a new **User.groovy** class in the same package as in the plugin & add all the fields. This looks a problem with extending domain classes, but this can be a temporary work around.

Comment: After an explicit typing of the currentUser as 'User currentUser =' (instead of using 'def') the ClassCastExceptions did not appear again.